# Any kind of custom post type in the front page and in the archive listing

Tags: archives, categories

I have a custom post type:products
to have my post from my custom post type i have changeed these codes

```
<?php
    $post_count = 1;
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
```

to

```
?php
    $post_count = 1;        $args = array(          'post_type' => 'products'       );      $products = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ($products->have_posts()) : while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post() ?>
```

I have done same things for the archive.php also.
But

Now what i want to do i wont to get posts from different post types on my front page. Not any.
And when i chose a category to get posts i want to get from different post types. Not any
thispart inside of archive.php
How we can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
  if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
     'post', 'post_type1', 'post_type2'
        ));
      return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

it worked realy good.

Answer (score 0):

you can try wordpress query like

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'any'
);
$query =WP_Query($args);

if( $query->have_posts() ){
  while($query->have_posts()){
    the_post();
    $hide_post_type = array(
      'attachment'
    );    

    // hide post type which you do not want to show
    if( in_array( get_post_type(),$hide_post_type))
      continue;

    //show your post of any type
  }
}
```

Comment: [code] <?php
$post_count = 1;
$args = array('post_type' => 'any');
$query =new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php  if($query->have_posts()): while($query->have_posts()): the_post()  ?>[/code] ı got erroe

Comment: How i can decide teh custompost categories than?

Comment: Fron any created othe rproblems for me. thats whay speciag post types more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding these code to fucntions.php

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
  if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
     'post', 'your_post_type'
        ));
      return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```